# Use specific codewords as arguments/prefixes in a message?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, arguments, discord.js

I'm working in JavaScript with [discord.js@v12](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12). I asked this question in their support Discord, but due to issue in question being more related to JavaScript than Discordjs, here I am!

Let's get on it. I would like to fill out a [RichEmbed](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embeds) in **one** single message. This RichEmbed will include a title, a description and **1** field. There can be more than one field in RichEmbeds, so I want to get it clear I only need **1**.

Now, I realize I could do this using the following ways **a)** using [awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) and filling in the info one message at a time **b)** Separating arguments in the message with a space and making each argument `text-like-this` **c)** Separating arguments in the message with a `newline` and making each line a full argument. However, neither of these look very appealing to me. I also have a few people who are going to use my command who are not very technical and thus may not understand the usage of the command unless having a very detailed explanation, which is not very efficient when I'm not available.

I've used **a)** in the past and it's proven rather unefficient in a fast workflow, and **b** is straight up useless if I require a long description with a lot of sentences. **C** is usable but, again, there will be people using this command who are not technically "capable" and thus may struggle on their own. I want to make this as fluent as I can.

I also tried this method, which I found fairly useful but can be confusing:

```
/commandname Separating title / Description and / Field by a forward slash
```

So I came to the conclusion I want my syntax looking **something** like this:

```
/commandname title:My title! desc:This is the description field1:Field 1 and its title
```

---

**EDIT:** I spent a bit of research after posting, and found out I can use `replace` method to get the above result. This is currently my code:

```js
let embed_title
let embed_desc
let embed_field
let firstarg = args[1]

if (firstarg.includes(`title:`)) {
    var split = firstarg.replace(`title:`, ``)
    embed_title = split
    // expected output with "/commandname title:Testing123!": /commandname Testing123!

} else if (firstarg.includes(`desc:`)) {
    var split = firstarg.replace(`desc:`, ``)
    embed_desc = split
    // expected output with "/commandname desc:Testing123!": /commandname Testing123!

} else if (firstarg.includes(`field:`)) {
    var split = firstarg.replace(`field:`, ``)
    embed_field = split
    // expected output with "/commandname field:Testing123!": /commandname Testing123!

}
```

With this I can easily replace the **first** argument that has `title:`, `desc:` or `field:` in it, however I'd like to scour through the whole message (`message.content`). After that, I want to find which argument has `title:` in it. Then I want to feed every argument **after** `title` until it hits `desc:`. Repeat that until `field` is covered.

Comment: If you have a string with fields delimited by `|`, and their count is constant, you may simply split the string with `|` and then build your output string using the obtained values. BTW, your **b)** is actually `string.split(/\s+/).join("-")`, or, if you need lowercasing, `string.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).join("-")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, this was my original idea. But then I realized that there may be cases where someone uses `/commandname The cool title | A cool field` and does **not** utilize  the description. In this case, the title gets **The cool title**, the description gets **A cool field** and the field winds up null. That is what I want to prevent. The correct value in the wrong "field".

Comment: Sorry, your actual programming problem is not clear. Please provide exact input string format description (specs), what toolset you have access to *and* **your best attempt to solve the problem**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What I have at the moment is this:`/commandname Title here / Description here / Field here` (this method works for me at the moment, but misusing one value messes up the whole order). **I want to utilize this**: `/commandname title:Title here desc:Description here field1: Field here`. I read that RegEx can solve this, but my experience with RegEx is not good enough to power this requirement and thus I'm stuck on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by using a different syntax.

Instead of using `/command` and then:

```
title:Title of message desc:Description of message field1:Field of message
```

I'm using `/command` and then:

```
title Title of new message
description Description of new message
field Field 1 of new message
```

I'm splitting the arguments by newline `\n` instead of space/whitespace.

```
const msgArray = message.content.split(/ +/g)
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length + msgArray[0].length).trim().split(`\n`)
```

Since I'm splitting the arguments by newline, it allows me to use spaces in my arguments without worrying about them coming out weird.

<s>I then check for each argument and if it begins with `Title`, `Description` or `Field`, **or** none of them. Then, I iterate through each argument (from **1** to **3** in human terms) and check if they start with any of the three, then go from there. **Note** that this is manual and does not have superb compatibility if I wish to add another field or an image, but this works for my case and thus, I've solved it for now.</s>

I realized this afternoon that I can simply loop through all the `args` and find which one contains a certain keyword. In the process, I can also filter out anything that does **not** match certain keyword(s).

Complete code as follows:

```js
var _title = ``
var _desc = ``
var _fieldvalue = ``
var _useless = ``

args.forEach((element, i) => {
  i += 1
  if (element.startsWith(`description `)) {
    _desc = element.slice(12)

  }else if (element.startsWith(`title `)) {
    _title = element.slice(6)

  }else if (element.startsWith(`field `)) {
    _fieldvalue = element.slice(6)

  }else{
    _useless = element
  }
})

if (!_title && !_desc) return message.channel.send(`Please include at least a title or a description by using \`title\` or \`description\`.`)

if (!_fieldvalue) {
  message.channel.send({embed: {
    title: _title || null,
    description: _desc || null,
  }})

} else {
  message.channel.send({embed: {
    title: _title || null,
    description: _desc || null,
    fields: [
      {
        name: `\u200b`,
        value: _fieldvalue,
      },
    ],
  }})

}
```

**For those of you who want to see the code for the original result, see this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HHdt7CJF) result**.